# Missing Method Exception - Signature parameter is long, called with an int

Tags: c#, exception, missingmethodexception

This code compiles, and runs successfully locally, but not on another server. Both machines are 64-bit operating systems.

This is the call:

```
retItem = (DataCollectionSetValueHeader)new DataCollectionSetValueHeaderLogic().GetItem(Id);  // Id is an int.
```

And this is the method signature that's being called:

```
public DataCollectionSetValueHeader GetItem(long entityID)  // This one is obviously a long
```

This compiles, so I'm assuming that it's okay to pass an int to a method that expects a long. The question, though, is why would this work locally, but fail with "MissingMethodException" on another machine?

We're struggling with where to begin troubleshooting this. Could a different version of the .NET framework cause this? Something else?

Comment: Is the method and the call in the same binary? Perhaps you’re only updating one of the two files if not.

Comment: Is this a new method that was introduced recently? I would suspect a flawed deployment.

Comment: @romkyns No, they are in different assemblies.

Comment: @code4life No, not recently. I suspect the issue may be what Jon Skeet suggests in his answer. We're looking at the decompiled source code in ILSpy now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This compiles, so I'm assuming that it's okay to pass an int to a method that expects a long.

No, it's not - not at the binary level. It's okay at the *source code* level, because the compiler turns your code into:

```
GetItem((long) Id)
```

But once you've compiled code which uses a method as if it's got an `int` parameter, you can't change the parameter type, recompile *just the assembly containing the method itself* and then expect the old binary to work. You'll need to recompile the calling code as well.

If you believe you're using the same binary (as the *target* of the call) in both places, then it must be something else.

Comment: Cool, that's good to know. But these same binaries work on one machine but not on another.

Comment: @BobHorn: Could you give more context about the code involved? Is the calling code in the same assembly as the method it's calling?

Comment: It is not. We're decompiling now to see if what you stated is exactly what happened.

Comment: So, the caller's decompiled code shows that Id is an int. And the method signature is a long. So the caller must have been compiled when a method existed that took an int, otherwise the compiler would have cast to a long like, you mentioned.

Comment: What you say makes sense. We're thinking that the server code was updated to a long, deployed as a hot fix, and that's why it's broken. Since the caller is an int, it was never compiled against the server version. Thanks, Jon.

Comment: @BobHorn: Yes, that would definitely do it.

Comment: This is exactly what happened. We just looked at the source code history, and that must be it. I'm suspecting that the report of it working on one machine was a mistake, because these same binaries won't work, no matter where they're deployed.